# How to make columns as wide as the widest entry?

Tags: markup, asciidoc

For a gcc cheatsheet I'm writing, I want to create a table which should describe how gcc interprets different file endings. The table I created so far is defined as follows:

```
|======================================================================
|.c    |C source code which must be preprocessed.
|.i    |C source code which should not be preprocessed.
|.h    |C header file to be turned into a precompiled header.
|.s    |Assembler code.
|other |
An object file to be fed straight into linking. Any file name with no
recognized suffix is treated this way.
|======================================================================
```

The problem I have is that the table spans the total page width, but what I want is that each column only is as wide as it's widest entry, and that the table will span only as much witdh as it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not a good idea to mix content and layout rules within the source file.

That is for a good reason: The layout definition of the table depends on the output format. If you use for example html as backend for the document, [css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) would be an appropriate technology to layout the document. On the other hand, e.g. if you use a formatting objects processor to create pdf files like [apache fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), automatic table-layout is not supported by all FO processors.

To answer your question: It depends on the output format, how the table layout will be defined correctly. A definition within the AsciiDoc markup is the wrong way in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to use a [horizontal list](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#_horizontal_labeled_list_style) in this case rather than a table. The rendered result is close to what you are looking for. The syntax would look like the following:

```
[horizontal]
+.c+:: C source code which must be preprocessed.
+.i+:: C source code which should not be preprocessed.
+.h+:: C header file to be turned into a precompiled header.
+.s+:: Assembler code.
other:: An object file to be fed straight into linking. Any file name with no recognized suffix is treated this way.
```